# Using turtle for drawing a hypothetical alphabet's digits

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw the hypothetical alphabet's digits by encoding the value as the corresponding number of lines, just to provide an example of what different methods of encoding could be used. I am facing two challenges.

Why would the `sqrt()` function not work in the below context? `atan()` works, so I should not be missing a library.

Why am I not able to change the color of the turtle's line mid-way using style? When I am trying to replace `blue` with `white` in the `draw` arguments in order to move a turtle from its home to the next character's starting point, and then to style it back to `blue`, nothing is visible.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{turtle}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[thick,blue,turtle=home,lt=180,fd=2];
    \draw[thick,blue,turtle=home,rt,fd=2,lt=180,how=/.style={color=blue},lt=180,fd,rt={180-atan(2)},fd={sqrt(5)}]; % 63.4349488 2.24
    \draw[thick,blue,turtle=home,rt,fd=4,lt=180,how=/.style={color=blue},lt=180,fd,rt={180-atan(2)},fd=2.24,left={180-atan(2)},fd];
    \draw[thick,blue,turtle=home,rt,fd=6,lt=180,how=/.style={color=blue},lt=180,fd,rt={90+45},fd=1.414,left={180-45},fd,rt={90+45},fd=1.414];
    \draw[thick,blue,turtle=home,rt,fd=8,lt=180,how=/.style={color=blue},lt=180,fd,rt={90+45},fd=1.414,left={180-45},fd,rt={90+45},fd=1.414,left={180-45},fd];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The goal is to not have the digits connected by the horizontal line.

[image: digits]

Comment: You might want to look into metafont and co. It's a tedious and painful way, but it _should_ be much better suited for what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome! I guess you want to use shifts instead of the forward movements.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{turtle}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[thick,blue,turtle={home,lt=180,fd=2}];
    \draw[xshift=2cm,thick,blue,turtle={home,rt,lt=180,lt=180,fd,rt={180-atan(2)},fd={2.23607}}]; % 63.4349488 2.24
    \draw[xshift=4cm,thick,blue,turtle={home,rt,lt=180,lt=180,fd,rt={180-atan(2)},fd=2.24,left={180-atan(2)},fd}];
    \draw[xshift=6cm,thick,blue,turtle={home,rt,lt=180,lt=180,fd,rt={90+45},fd=1.414,left={180-45},fd,rt={90+45},fd=1.414}];
    \draw[xshift=8cm,thick,blue,turtle={home,rt,lt=180,lt=180,fd,rt={90+45},fd=1.414,left={180-45},fd,rt={90+45},fd=1.414,left={180-45},fd}];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

BTW, there were some minor errors/typos. The key `how/.style={color=blue},` does not have an effect (as pointed out by Henri Menke), and more importantly, you have participated in the discovery of an [issue](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/789): `fd` does not seem to parse its expression. This issue will be fixed in version 3.1.5.

Comment: Maybe you want to added the `/.evaluated` variant to your answer.

Comment: @HenriMenke Didn't you say "This new handler will be built into the next release."?

Comment: Yes, but it's only four lines of code, so you can just copy it to your document to use it already.

Comment: @HenriMenke I find this a bit pointless, sorry. I found a bug here, reported it, and added a simple workaround. And I answered a question.